# Have IPython echo variable without print() call using SublimeREPL

Tags: ipython, sublimetext, sublimerepl

In IPython, typing a variable name at the command line will automatically print the contents of the variable.

> In [75]: x = 1
>
> In [76]: x
>
> Out[76]: 1

However, when passing code from a file into IPython via the SublimeREPL plugin in Sublime Text, I have to run `print(x)` if I want to see anything (I'm using Windows in case it matters). To be explicit, my code is in a separate file, and I'm passing the line of code into IPython for execution via SublimeREPL's Ctrl+,l shortcut. Is there a way I can just pass `x` instead of `print(x)` and see the contents of `x`?